# anchor tag getting appended multiple times to child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html that has images embedded into links.I am trying to append an achor tag into the div,however the anchor tags gets added multiple times.
this is my code original

```
<div id="Banner" style="display: block; position: relative;">
<div id="Settings" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></div>
<div >
 <a href="/id=10052&;way=ban">
  <img src="/hours.jpg">
 </a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="/id=10220&amp;way=ban">
 <img src="/rq.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

now i am trying to add in another anchor tag as follows the expected outcome

```
<div id="Banner" style="display: block; position: relative;">
    <div id="Settings" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></div>
    <div >
     <a href="#" class="previous"></a>  // tag to come in
     <a href="/id=10052&;way=ban">
      <img src="/hours.jpg">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="previous"></a>  // tag to come in
    <a href="/id=10220&amp;way=ban">
     <img src="/rq.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

this is my code i tried

```
var container = $($('#Banner').children('div'));
var previous = $('<a href="#" class="previous">');
previous.appendTo(container);
```

and this is what is happening

```
<div id="Banner" style="display: block; position: relative;">
    <div id="Settings" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></div>
    <div >
     <a href="#" class="previous"></a>  // tag to come in
    <a href="#" class="previous"></a> //added multiple times
   <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
   <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
   <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
     <a href="/id=10052&;way=ban">
      <img src="/hours.jpg">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="previous"></a>  // tag to come in
   <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>  //added multiple times
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
 <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
    <a href="/id=10220&amp;way=ban">
     <img src="/rq.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

it keeps appending the tag multiple times. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `appendTo` function it's not checked only `append`

Comment: Very first you need to check already `added` or not

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/opuxbfah/ are you doing this in a loop or something?

Comment: As shown in @Pete 's helpful jsfiddle, and would have been shown if you'd create a snippet in the question, the code you've provided does not do what you're claiming **as provided**.  The next step is for either us to *guess* what the problem might be (and possibly be right...running it more than once?) or for you to provide a *demonstrable example* in the form of a snippet that demonstrates the problem.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: @jishansiddique *"You are using appendTo function it's not checked only append"* - not sure what this means.  They both work the same way, just with targets swapped.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your function keeps repeating. So, you may possibly set a simple check to make sure it's done only once:

```
var container = $('#Banner').children('div');
var previous = $('<a href="#" class="previous">');
// Check if element already exists before appending.
if (container.find(".previous").length === 0)
  previous.appendTo(container);
```

This way, it checks if the DOM element exists before it appends. I really feel that the big picture needs some alteration, but for this case, this solution should work out.